# How many Book Can I Divid Between Kids

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

1.If I have 12 books,in how many ways can I divid them between 4 kids , If every kid must get 3 books?

2.If I have 12 books and the 2 kids get 4 books each and 2 other kids get 2 book each?

No more information was given in the question.

Ant help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This supposes the kids are distinguished, and the books too.

Order the books in any order (12!), and then divide by the (irrelevant) order of the books within each kid (3!), so the solution is

$$
\frac{12!}{3!^4}
$$

and in the other case

$$
\frac{12!}{4!^2 * 2!^2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_i$ denote book $i$; $K_j$ denote kid $j$.

---

**1.**
First we want to order the books in a specific way. That makes
$$12!$$
Possibilies for a sequence
$$(B_i, B_j, \ldots)$$
Let the first $3$ books belong to $K_1$, the second $3$ to $K_2$ and so on; then to have the same distribution of books, we can interchange them within each pair of $3$. For this there are $3!$ possibilities, so in total we have
$$N = \frac{12!}{3!^4} = 369600$$
possibilities.

---

**2.**
Can you do this yourself?